# PHP Messing Up XML File

Tags: php, ios, xml

I have an app in which I send a $POST to a php script, with the purpose of adding a new item to an XML file.  Every once in a while, the XML will add a bunch of blank fields, making it impossible to properly parse.  The end of the XML looks like this:

```
<item><first_name/><last_name/><title/><date/><anonymous/><prayer_warriors>0</prayer_warriors><location/><description/><iostoken/></item>
```

The script I use looks like:

```
<?php
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
 $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
 $request = $_POST['request'];
 $anon = $_POST['anon'];
 $pubDate = $_POST['pubDate'];
 $loc = $_POST['loc'];
 $des = $_POST['des'];
 $iostoken = $_POST['iostoken'];
//This line will load the XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://Test.xml") or die("Not loaded!\n");
//print_r($xml);
//This line gets the channel element (from an array returned by the xpath method) 
$channel = $xml->xpath('//channel'); 
$channel = $channel[0];
//print_r($channel);
$person = $channel->addChild("item");
$person->addChild("first_name", $firstName);
$person->addChild("last_name", $lastName);
$person->addChild("title", $request);
$person->addChild("date", $pubDate);
$person->addChild("anonymous", $anon);
$person->addChild("prayer_warriors", "0");
$person->addChild("location", $loc);
$person->addChild("description", $des);
$person->addChild("iostoken", $iostoken);

//This next line will overwrite the original XML file with new data added
$xml->asXML("Test.xml");
?>
```

Anything look wrong on this script that would cause empty tags?

The $_POST comes from the info that is sent from my app that I have built for this.  Basically, I have text fields for first name, last name, device token, prayer request, title, and description, and date, and it uses the PHP to take those fields and put them in the XML file.  The PHP works, as I can enter text in those fields and edit the XML, but every once in a while it adds that at the end, and my app won't parse, and crashes.

My parser in the app looks like:

```
- (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

    NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {

        NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];

        NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

            NSString *firstName = [item valueForChild:@"first_name"];
            NSString *lastName = [item valueForChild:@"last_name"];
            NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"date"];
            NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
            int daysToAdd = 7;
            NSDate *newDate1 = [articleDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
            NSString *anonymous = [item valueForChild:@"anonymous"];
            NSString *prayerRequest = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
            NSString *prayerWarriors = [item valueForChild:@"prayer_warriors"];
            NSString *location = [item valueForChild:@"location"];
            NSString *details = [item valueForChild:@"description"];
            NSString *devicestoken = [item valueForChild:@"iostoken"];
            NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
            [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            NSString *dateofarticle = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:articleDate];
            NSString *expirationDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate1];
            NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
            NSComparisonResult result = [today compare:articleDate];
            NSString *bodyoftext = [[[[[[@"<b><font size=5><div align=\"left\">" stringByAppendingString:prayerRequest] stringByAppendingString:@"</font></b><font size=3><p style=\"color:#989898\">"] stringByAppendingString:@"Expires " ] stringByAppendingString:expirationDate] stringByAppendingString:@"</div></p>"] stringByAppendingString:details];

            RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle firstName:firstName lastName:lastName articleDate:articleDate prayerRequest:prayerRequest anonymous:anonymous prayerWarriors:prayerWarriors location:location details:bodyoftext expiresDate:newDate1 iostoken:devicestoken] autorelease];
            switch (result)
            {
                case NSOrderedAscending:
                    NSLog(@"Future Date");
                    break;
                case NSOrderedDescending:


                    [entries addObject:entry];
                    NSLog(@"Earlier Date");
                    break;
                case NSOrderedSame:


                    [entries addObject:entry];
                    NSLog(@"Today/Null Date Passed"); //Not sure why This is case when null/wrong date is passed
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"Error Comparing Dates");
                    break;
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Empty tags like `<first_name/>` do not make XML "impossible to parse."  That's normal for when you have no innerText. Most parsers prefer `<first_name/>` over `<first_name></first_name>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your $_POST is empty or doesn't contain the structure you think it does. Since prayer_warriors correctly has the value of 0 in the XML, it looks like the $firstName, $lastName, $request, etc. are empty variables. Can you do a debug print such as print_r($_POST) and see what it looks like?

Also, as @developerwjk mentioned in a comment, `<tagname />` is perfectly valid XML. If you're trying to parse the XML structure with regular expressions or anything other than an XML parser, stop immediately and use an XML parser.

Comment: The $_POST comes from the info that is sent from my app that I have built for this.  Basically, I have text fields for first name, last name, device token, prayer request, title, and description, and date, and it uses the PHP to take those fields and put them in the XML file.  The PHP works, as I can enter text in those fields and edit the XML, but every once in a while it adds that at the end, and my app won't parse, and crashes.

Comment: If `$person->addChild("first_name", $firstName);` is creating a tag that looks like `<first_name />` then `$firstName` is either null or the empty string.

Comment: But other attempts at using the PHP to add to it have worked fine, and the app won't allow sending anything until all fields are occupied.

Comment: You could always add something like `if(!isset($_POST['firstName'])) die()` to the top of the script.

Comment: It seems the reason the app is failing is because it tries to convert the date from NSString to NSDate in code for each item, but because the date tag is empty, it crashes.  My question is just why is the XML getting these empty tags?

Comment: Then use my previous comment to check if `$_POST['$pubDate']` is set before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll make that change, and if the issue stops, I'll come back and mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: You may not want to check only for `isset()` but also that it's not the empty string. Always validate input data. :)